# Find the minimum value of $k$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^5 (PP_i)^2 = k$, $P_i = (r,r^2)$

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> P is a point on the coordinate plane. Find the minimum value of $k$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^5 (PP_i)^2 = k$$ where $P_i = (i,i^2)$. ($PP_i$) denotes the distance between point $P$ and point $P_i$

This question (and the associated answer) do not make sense. If $P = (0,0)$ and $P_i$ are chosen to be $(0,0), (1,\pm1), (2,\pm 4)$, then the value of $k$ is $44$. The answer mentioned, however is $384$.

Could someone guide me in the correct direction to solve this question?

Comment: There seems to be quite a bit missing: The way you wrote down the question, everything could also just be (0,0) and k would also be 0. I would suggest you either ask the person who proposed the problem to clarify, or you move on to a clearer problem.

Comment: The minimum is $384$ for $P_i = (i,i^2),  1 \le i \le 5$

Comment: @achillehui could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: $P_i$ are not 5 arbitrary points but $P_1 = (1,1)$, $P_2 = (2,4)$, $P_3 = (3,9)$ and so on. If you minimize the sum of square of distances to these 5 points, you get $384$.

Comment: @achillehui I double checked and I was wrong in interpreting the question. Updated the question here to reflect that.